# Java - Sort wildcard array when superclass implements Comparable

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, annotations, wildcard

I implemented an annotation interface:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface SuperClassAnnotation
{
    Class<? extends SuperClass>[] subClasses();
}
```

Used in another class in this way:

```
@SuperClassAnnotation(
        subClasses = {
                SubClass1.class,
                SubClass2.class,
                SubClass3.class,
                SubClass4.class,
                SubClass5.class,
                SubClass6.class
                }
        )
```

When I retrieve the `subClasses`, I want to sort the array.

`SuperClass` implements `Comparable` and has an abstract method `getDisplayName()`. This is what I compare in the `compareTo` method.

I sort the array by:

```
Class<? extends SuperClass>[] subClassArray = supportedSubClasses.subClasses();
Arrays.sort(subClassArray);
```

but I get a runtime error on the `Arrays.sort` line:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(ComparableTimSort.java:290)
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:157)
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:146)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:472)
    at edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:76)
```

Is what I'm trying to achieve possible? Or should I consider a different approach?

Comment: What you are passing to `sort` is an array of Class. It will simply try to compare the objects in this array which are of type `Class`. If you need to sort your SuperClass objects, you will need to pass an array of SuperClass. Also your `subClasses` method is returning an array of class!! and not actual instances of those classes on which you can call the `compareTo` which invokes your `getDisplayName()`

Comment: Yes I am aware of this. The reason why I retain Class<? extends SuperClass> is because I call .newInstance() when looping through the array later on, which can't be done if I just pass SuperClass.